# How to Install PHP MongoDB Driver for XAMPP on MAC OS

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

On : sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo

The following is the error I get :

sudo: setrlimit(8): Invalid argument
WARNING: "pecl/mongo" is deprecated in favor of "channel:///mongodb"
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
pecl/mongo requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 5.99.99), installed version is 7.3.10
No valid packages found
install failed

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that mongo extension is deprecated, and you should use mongodb instead:

```
pecl install mongodb
```